# Can someone explain, in clear terms (not unmathematical) what short circuit is?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, definition, short-circuits

I don't get the idea about what short circuit is. In a few questions I have come across, it appears to be a short circuit but the answers say otherwise. In fact, I don't have a conceptual understanding about it.

Comment: How do you mean "answers say otherwise"?

Answer (score 1):

A short-circuit fault is an **unintended** connection between two points in an electrical circuit.

In power systems this may be phase-ground, phase-phase, or combinations thereof.

Note, sometimes a short-circuit is applied intentionally.  We add the term **fault** when it is unintentional.

Answer (score 1):

A short circuit is a situation in which, somewhere in your circuit, there is a very low resistence path (in the limit, with resistence $r\to 0$).

Let's see what I mean with a simple example. We'll proceed step by step so bear with me.

Imagine you have this situation: you have a voltage source $V$ (a battery) connected to a resistance $R$ (the lamp on your desk). The circuit is designed in a way that, given the house voltage $V$ (usually 220V) the amount of current which circulates in the system is reasonable. Such an amount is given by Ohm's law as
$$I=V/R$$

What do I mean by reasonable?

a) safe enough. That's not usually the case for a desk lamp, but one can try to tune the flowing current so that it's very low. For example, the current coming out of your phone charger is very small. Also the current flowing through your computer is usually small, otherwise the components may burn.

b) cheap enough. The power your appliance consume is given by $P=V^2/R$. At fixed voltage (your house voltage) objects with a big resistence consume less power. If $R$ is very small, you can suck all of the energy out of your network.

b2) safe enough 2: if the current is high, the power is high and that leads to heat: your appliance might burn and cause a fire!

Now, imagine the bulb of your lamp has a given resistence $R$ such that the current it would consume is unreasonable. What what can do is put another resistence $R_0$ *in series* so that the total current flowing is going to be
$$I=V/(R+R_0)$$
and one can tune $R_0$ in a way that the current is reasonable. This is maybe not standard electrical practice, but you can always think of your circuit as a total resistence under a total voltage to make things simpler. It is however true that you need to step down your current often, especially if your components (your phone, your circuit..) would be damaged by a high current.

**So now, what is a short circuit?**

If for *some* reason (a damage? a wrong construction choice) the extra resistence of your circuit $R_0$ becomes small, maybe because the current finds an "alternative" way or because the resistor breaks and current manages to flow through it freely, you get a sudden, intense increase in current which can cause damage both to you or to the object. The extra resistence you added to shield you from high current has failed you (notice that in the opposite case in which $R_0$ survives and $R$ goes to 0, $R_0$ will save you from a short circuit, if it was chosen in a smart way).

In the simple limit in which the total resistence $R_T$ becomes $0$ (becaue also $R$ goes to 0 or because $R<<R_0$ anyways..) you get
$$I=V/R_T=\infty$$
That is usually called a short circuit.

There is another circumstance which we should mention. I mentioned that sometimes current finds "an alternative way". For example, if you drop water (very low resistance) on your plug, current has now two choices: going through the lamp as it usually does, or getting immediately back to the plug travelling through water. Because water has a very low resistence, current chooses that path and thus (again, because of low resistence) the current can become very high: explosions and such.

This is because when you have to resistances in parallel (your lamp $R$ and water $r$) current will travel mostly through the lowest one. This is because the total resistence of the parallel is
$$R_T=Rr/(R+r)$$
and you see that if $r\to 0$ then the whole thing $R_T\to 0$ and the total current $I=V/R_T\to\infty$!
This is also a short circuit.

Summing up, a short circuit is a situation in which for some reason the *total* resistence of your circuit becomes *very* small thus causing intense current.

In the case of a series $R+R_0$ it can be because one of the two (or both) resistances fail you. If only one fails, the second one might save you.

In the case of a parallel $Rr/(R+r)$ it's because one of the two is much smaller than the other. In one fails, you're fried.

Answer (score 0):

A short circuit is a fault that basically creates an unwanted electrical conduction path from an electrical source to ground.  This results in drawing too much current from the electrical source and tripping protection devices- fuses and circuit breakers- to prevent burning out the electrical source.

Comment: It does not need "ground". It is not necessarily a fault (for example when measuring the short-circuit current of a photovoltaic cell).

Comment: @Pieter  Thanks for the comment.  I thought the question was about an electrical short, but as you say a short circuit is a broader concept.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple Mathematical explanation of short circuit.

Electrical power $$P = V^2/R$$ where V is voltage difference and R is electrical resistance.

If R is very low, for the same Voltage difference V, the power is very high. (Also, the current $$i= V/R$$ is very high.) This situation is a short circuit and all this energy leads to overheating, fires etc.

Answer (score 0):

A short circuit is when the main electrical power source wire accidentally touches something that is connected to ground or to the return line in the power supply. The entire output of the power source then flows through this connection. The resulting current will be very large- sometime large enough to heat the power-carrying wires enough to set them on fire.

Answer (score 0):

I find examples are sometimes the best way to explain to a lay person a concept, take for instance a battery which most are familiar with a positive and negative post, now its very critical not to touch the two together, otherwise extreme heat will occur, and very likely will explode.  This in essence is a short circuit, or shorting the battery. In normal operation of a battery, the positive side is connected to what we refer to as loads, example the car starter, headlights, and so forth, and all these devices need the positive side, along with a return connection back to the negative side of the battery. Now you can look at a house in the same way, instead of a battery you have power coming into the house from the power panel or disconnect box which again has a positive side or refer to hot side, going out to many devices that need power, and a return wire is needed to complete the circuit. Now the difference with power coming into the house is that the negative side is also connected to earth ground, so naturally now if you happen to touch a hot wire and your not insulated in anyway from the ground your standing on, you now cause yourself to be short-circuited, or another words will be shocked and that can be serious or many times fatal.

Comment: not unmathematical ...should try to avoid two negatives

Answer (score 0):

A short circuit is a pathway of little or no resistance between two points in a pathway/circuit/pipe which has larger resistance. It allows current to flow more freely than the original path.

In an electrical system it may be a fault which causes overtaxing/overheating of a power supply or allows a larger voltage to appear across other components. For example, if there are two $50~\Omega$ resistors in series with each other and a $100$ V voltage supply which is limited to $1.5$ A. Ordinarily, the current needed would be $1$ A. If a bare wire accidently connects the "front" of the first resistor to its "end", the current needed would be $2$ A and the voltage supply would not function properly, depending on its designed failure mode (fuse, thermal shutdown, low voltage cut-in).

Short circuits in both fluid (liquid or gas) and electrical systems could also be introduced by design to produce specific changes in total circuit behavior.

TL;DR: it's an alternate path, generally of lower resistance.